# Can we add a section in our vf page and add components to it

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

Can we add a section in our vf page and add components to it. I mean split my vf page into two parts and then add components to it.

Comment: Yes, we can do it.

Comment: how can we do it ?????

Comment: You should create a new section `apex:pageBlockSection` with parameter `columns`  set to 2. Then insert your components in each column.

Comment: still no changes.

Comment: Posting your page would be helpful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of the simplest section with two columns:

```
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
            <c:yourComponent1/>
            <c:yourComponent2/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```